# fatal Error undefined function switch_to_blog()

Tags: multisite, switch-to-blog

Hello All!

I got this puzzling beginner issue. It's my first Multisite install, latest versions of all, no plugins, and when I am trying to use in a page template the switch_to_blog function, I get this :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function switch_to_blog() in
>   /SITES/Sitename/wp-content/themes/themename/page.php on line 28

with line 28 :                  *switch_to_blog(1);*

I must do something wrong, but it looks the function itself is not installed, though the function's file is there (as it should be in any normal install).

Is there a way to cleanly create the function, declare it or activate it ?
I tried copy the function switch_to_blog to functions.php, and there is does not complain but is not working (i got the article from the CURRENT blog). but then error make it stop to *restore_current_blog();* with the same fatal error...

I don't know where to begin... what might help you understand the issue ?
THANKS in advance.

G.

Comment: It should be in wp-includes/ms-blogs.php, do you see it there?

Comment: Yes there it is...

Comment: I am using MAMP 3 and 4, same result.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/242043/edit) to add in the relevant code. Are you calling this in an action or a filter? If so, which one?

Comment: I got this error when I used switch_to_blog() inside the functions.php file of my theme, in a single site installation of WordPress 4.8.9. In a multisite installation, with the same WP version, the error did not occur! About the page.php file, I did not have any problem using that function inside it.

Answer (score 0):

*Some time ago, but i ran into exactly the same misbehavior.*

Have your **multisite activated and installed** correctly.

Because WordPress is just loading the functions when a multisite is really active.
Here the code from `wp-settings.php` file around line 137 on WP 6.1.1

```
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-site-query.php';
    require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-network-query.php';
    require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/ms-blogs.php'; // <--- switch_to_blog() is in here!!
    require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/ms-settings.php';
} elseif ( ! defined( 'MULTISITE' ) ) {
    define( 'MULTISITE', false );
}
```

---

Here i found a long read tutorial which helped me a lot: https://multilingualpress.org/docs/how-to-install-wordpress-multisite/

But there should be alternatives findable anyway.